# Android Asynctask - static variables removes after execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask to load Texture assets.I put my texture variables into a different class with static modifier.I debug my app and i see that when asynctask is executing ,it loads textures into my static variables but after it executed,all my variables are changing to null.What can be a problem about that?

```
public class Assets{
public static Texture logo;
}


protected Boolean doInBackground(GLGame... game) {
      publishProgress(10);

    Assets.logo = new Texture(glGame, "logo3.png");
}
```

Comment: could you give some code to see if there's an error?

Comment: try to initialize the Texture logo into the activity onCreate and on doInBackground modify the content of logo. I don't understand why this code you paste doesn't work... sorry :(

Comment: @droidmachine, Can we see your postExecute method too?

Comment: @yugidroid I'm not using a postExecute method.

Comment: @droidmachine, in that case, I would suggest you to do what Litus said before. Initialize Texture object in you onCreate.

Comment: @yugidroid What is the difference?

Comment: @droidmachine, Your code seems good and I don't understand what could set your values to null! Your AsyncTask for some reason is is losing some data references... If you initialize that Texture in the onCreate it should work unless your activity is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you've provided enough code to answer this question.  Can you include your entire AsyncTask class definition along with how you are instantiating it and executing it.